# Regex - Extracting individual notes from a prepending notelog

Tags: regex

Got a situation where currently notes logged by users are saved to a single file, with a timestamp, userid, and the note.

I would like to extract each instance of a note, and put it into a spreadsheet.

For the usernames, I have `\([\w']+?, [\w']+?[ \w]{0,2}\) &#58;` (http://regexr.com/3fjf5)

The dates will be similarly trivial.

The part with which I'm struggling is grabbing the text following the timestamp and username. I tried using a negative lookahead for timestamp/username, but this will not work for the final line in the log, as it is not followed by a timestamp/username combo.

I have a solutions that involve appending a delimiter, or making two passes with regex, but I'm curious whether this can be done in a single pass.

Here's a sample of the text:

```
br><br>13/03/2015 10&#58;00  (Stone, Fred B) &#58; Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet &#160; - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.&#160; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. In velit massa, porta et arcu hendrerit, 
pellentesque pellentesque orci. Etiam ac ante pharetra, elementum nunc in, 
gravida lacus. Quisque sollicitudin, tellus at imperdiet condimentum, orci ante 
accumsan elit, sit amet lacinia enim purus eu nisl. Phasellus ullamcorper 
vestibulum tortor id fringilla.<br><br>2015-03-13T10&#58;00&#58;13  (Stone, Fred 
B) &#58; Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. 
Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae 
consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet 
et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo.<br><br>13/03/2015 09&#58;58  (Stone, Fred B) 
&#58; <br>  Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. 
Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae 
consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet 
et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br> Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, 
dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a 
augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis 
nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br><br>11/03/2015 
11&#58;12 (Smith, Mark L) &#58; Assigned to&#58; Stone, Fred B L<br>Quisque 
ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor 
odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. 
Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus 
volutpat leo<br><br>11/03/2015 11&#58;09  (Johnson, Rod R) &#58; <br>  Quisque 
ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor 
odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. 
Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus 
volutpat leo<br><br>19/02/2015 15&#58;30 (Smith, Mark L) &#58; Assigned to&#58; 
Stone, Fred B LQuisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie 
risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, 
vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, 
imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo
```

Resulting matches (italicized) should look like:

13/03/2015 10:00  (Stone, Fred B) : *Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet   - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. In velit massa, porta et arcu hendrerit, 
pellentesque pellentesque orci. Etiam ac ante pharetra, elementum nunc in, 
gravida lacus. Quisque sollicitudin, tellus at imperdiet condimentum, orci ante 
accumsan elit, sit amet lacinia enim purus eu nisl. Phasellus ullamcorper 
vestibulum tortor id fringilla.*

2015-03-13T10:00:13  (Stone, Fred B) : *Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo.*

etc.

Even returning each note (including the timestamp and UID) in a match would be acceptable. e.g.

*13/03/2015 10:00  (Stone, Fred B) : Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet   - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. In velit massa, porta et arcu hendrerit, 
pellentesque pellentesque orci. Etiam ac ante pharetra, elementum nunc in, 
gravida lacus. Quisque sollicitudin, tellus at imperdiet condimentum, orci ante 
accumsan elit, sit amet lacinia enim purus eu nisl. Phasellus ullamcorper 
vestibulum tortor id fringilla.*

Comment: You know, there is that <br> thing in there. Is that always the case?

Comment: Good question. It does not appear in front of the first note, but appears at the start of each subsequent note.

Comment: I would delete all the <br>'s as they can't be trusted as a delimiter. The only way this can be done is to define a strong regex for the _timestamp_ and _name_. Since they start a record, between them are the _note_. So, anything in the _note_ is all that is not a timestamp and name. Pseudo regex: `(?s)(timestamp)(name)((?:(?!timestamp name).)*))` Then you have your 3 groups of data.

Comment: For example, given @net-User regex, with a little more, you'd get the 3 parts http://regexr.com/3fjvo `/(?s)(\d{2,4}[\/-]{1}\d{1,2}[\/-]{1}\d{2,4}[:0-9T&#;\s]*?)(\([\w']+?,[ ][\w']+?[ \w]{0,2}\)[:0-9T&#;\s]*)((?:(?!\d{2,4}[\/-]{1}\d{1,2}[\/-]{1}\d{2,4}[:0-9T&#;\s]*?\([\w']+?,[ ][\w']+?[ \w]{0,2}\)[:0-9T&#;\s]*).)*)/`

Comment: Thanks sln, you did it. Now to decipher what you actually did and run some tests.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this can help you (I'm not sure i did understand you):

```
/\d{2,4}[\/-]{1}\d{1,2}[\/-]{1}\d{2,4}[:0-9T&#;\s]*?\([\w']+?, [\w']+?[ \w]{0,2}\)/g
```

http://regexr.com/3fjvl

You can make the regex more specific if you want so.

Comment: I was asking about the text body of the note, but I'll use this to pull out the timestamp and user, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string maybe something like this: (first `<` was missed in your sample)

```js
var mytext = "<br><br>13/03/2015 10&#58;00  (Stone, Fred B) &#58; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet &#160; - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.&#160; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In velit massa, porta et arcu hendrerit, pellentesque pellentesque orci. Etiam ac ante pharetra, elementum nunc in, gravida lacus. Quisque sollicitudin, tellus at imperdiet condimentum, orci ante accumsan elit, sit amet lacinia enim purus eu nisl. Phasellus ullamcorper vestibulum tortor id fringilla.<br><br>2015-03-13T10&#58;00&#58;13  (Stone, Fred B) &#58; Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo.<br><br>13/03/2015 09&#58;58  (Stone, Fred B) &#58; <br>  Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br> Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br><br>11/03/2015 11&#58;12 (Smith, Mark L) &#58; Assigned to&#58; Stone, Fred B L<br>Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br><br>11/03/2015 11&#58;09  (Johnson, Rod R) &#58; <br>  Quisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo<br><br>19/02/2015 15&#58;30 (Smith, Mark L) &#58; Assigned to&#58; Stone, Fred B LQuisque ipsum risus, cursus at purus in, dignissim molestie risus. Aliquam vitae auctor odio. Morbi condimentum sapien a augue accumsan, vitae consequat tortor feugiat. Nam quis consequat lectus. Duis nisl justo, imperdiet et ipsum nec, cursus volutpat leo" ;

//Define Regex patterns:

var dataReg = new RegExp(/(?:^|<br><br>)(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\d{2})&#58;(\d{2})\s*?\((\w+,[\w\s]+?)\)\s*&#58;\s*([^]+?)(?=<br><br>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}&#58;\d{2}|$)/g) ;

//Extract Notes and Data:
var myData = [] ;
while ((myData = dataReg.exec(mytext)) !== null) {
  console.log(myData);
}
```

Description of Regex Pattern: ([regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tzuOLv/2))

- `/`: regex pattern starts
- `(?:^|<br><br>)`: start search from beginning or new `<br><br>` that comes date and time after it.
- `(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) (\d{2})&#58;(\d{2})`: extract date,hour and minute separated.
- `\s*?`: pass spaces
- `\((\w+,[\w\s]+?)\)`: extract username inside the parenthesis `(..)`
- `\s*&#58;\s*`: pass the `:`
- `([^]+?)`: capture all **user notes**
- `(?=<br><br>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}&#58;\d{2}|$)`: stop capturing when next note or end of string is reached
- `/g`: Global flag means do not return after first successful result

Note:

[0] is all matched string

[1] is date , [2] is hour, [3] is minutes, [4] is username

[5] is user's note